# Correct sources.list when upgrading from stable to testing

Tags: raspbian, apt, update

Last night I followed [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/raspbian-gnu-linux-upgrade-from-jessie-to-raspbian-stretch-9) to upgrade my headless pi server from Jessie to Stretch. Everything worked as expected and the version output is now Stretch:

```
cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs
```

However, when I run `apt-upgrade` apt is failing to get the `Release` packages for Stretch. If I were to make an assumption it would be this is because Stretch is still in testing (thus not released). Despite my best efforts to [read](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) [about](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository) [Raspbian/Debian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59432/how-are-raspbian-repositories-organized) [Packages](https://sites.google.com/site/mydebiansourceslist/), I'm failing to get a complete grasp on what they should be when using `testing` instead of stable.

Here's the originally error when running `apt-get update`

```
Ign:1 http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/raspbian/raspbian stretch InRelease           
Ign:2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch InRelease            
Err:3 http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/raspbian/raspbian stretch Release             
  Unable to connect to mirrors.cat.pdx.edu:http:
```

Browsing to the mirror I see that a "Release" folder is present.

I also tried changing `stretch` to `testing` to see if that would yeield better results. Yet in this case `armf` failed as well as `jessie` packages.

```
Err:6 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian testing/main armhf Packages
  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:
Ign:5 http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/raspbian/raspbian testing/main all Packages
Err:7 http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/raspbian/raspbian testing/main armhf Packages
...
  Unable to connect to mirrors.cat.pdx.edu:http:
Err:38 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian jessie Release
  Unable to connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:http: [IP: 46.235.227.11 80]
```

My `sources.list` currently looks like this:

```
deb  http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/raspbian/raspbian  testing main contrib non-free rpi 
deb  http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian   testing main contrib non-free rpi
```

I'm hoping this is a case where I'm overlooking something basic in how packages works. Any help ya'll can provide would be amazing.

**EDIT:**
Looks like the main problem was an incorrect static IP setup. I resolved it by following [this guide](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/14183). I am still getting a few errors, but I think that may be because I'm using an unreleased versions. Any thoughts on how to correct the following would be great:

```
W: The repository 'http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 46.235.227.11 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```